# "provided me" or "provided to me"

Tags: prepositions

I was writing a letter and got confused with this line.

> I am thankful for the opportunities that have been provided me during
>   my tenure.

or should it be

> I am thankful for the opportunities that have been provided ***to*** me during my tenure.

Comment: I think I have come across another similar question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Provided to me" is grammatically correct, but "provided me" is a common, older, narrative style. You'll find other examples where "to" is missing but implicit, such as "Elizabeth, it has been so long since you have written me that I was quite sure you had forgotten me!"

If you are writing the letter then I would include the "to"; omitting it might appear inappropriately stylized, maybe even pompous.